# FriendA and FriendB are also friends with each other. Can FriendB see if FriendA likes/comments a post meant for FriendA only?

Tags: facebook-privacy

I tried to find existing answer but could not find the exact situation. I would like to know how Facebook will behave in the following case:

A, a friend of mine
B, a friend of mine
C, a friend of A, NO friend of mine

A and B are also friends with each other.

I post something limited to A ONLY.
A likes/comments the post.

How will B and C be affected?

Can B and C see the post?